# Get single Meta Name

Tags: c#

I have a pagehtml with this meta

```
<meta name="known" content="xxx">  
<meta name="city" content="xxx">
```

and use this code for return the meta

```
HtmlDocument domDocument = webBrowser1.Document;
  HtmlElementCollection metaElements = domDocument.GetElementsByTagName ("meta"); // get all the meta elements
  foreach (HtmlElement meta in metaElements)
  {
      string name = meta.GetAttribute("name");
      string content = meta.GetAttribute("content");
      // get more attributes if needed, then make it do something useful.
      // for lack of a better idea...
      MessageBox.Show(name + content);
  }
```

but return all meta ex: "city xxx", new messagebox "know xxx" etc... i need only meta content of city it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (name == "city")
    // Got it!
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
domDocument.GetElementsByTagName("meta")
           .First(m => m.GetAttribute("name") == "city")
```

Comment: and content?? contet is a variable

Comment: @Federal09: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: yeh it work if (name == "city")
      {
          MessageBox.Show(name + content);
      } nice idea thansk so much